# How can I output a model's fields separated on newlines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

In the console I can use `User` that outputs all the fields and their types for a user ex:

`User(id: integer, name: string)`

How can I format this output so that each field is on it's own line ie:

`User(
  id: integer,
  name: string
)`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just for info/debug purposes, you can for instance:

```
puts User.attribute_names
```

For more info:

```
puts User.columns.map { |c| "#{c.name} => #{c.type}" }
```

Comment: Awesome! The second is exactly what I want (replacing the hash rocket for a colin).

Is there any way to alias this command for ease of use?

Comment: Not really, you would put it in a gem, or maybe in a initializer to copy across projects.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry, I can't upvote you because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) gem to format objects when working in the console. Depending on what problem you're actually trying to solve here that might save you from reinventing a wheel.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. More of a long-term solution. Do you have any good tips on setting this up for a local-only development environment? I don't want to change the code for my whole team! I added the info to the .irbrc file, but it doesn't seem to work.